Unit test for class with BaseModel
I have below class and need to write a unit test for it using pytest I guess
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
class cl1(BaseModel):
    a1 :str = Field(None,title="blablabla")
    a2 :str = Field(None,title="blabla2")
    a3 :int = Field(title="bbbb1", default=0)
    a4 :int = Field(title="bbbb2", default=10000)

I tried this way but it failed with TypeError: can only concatenate str not ("NoneType") to str
import pytest
from mymodule import cl1
def test_cl1_defaults():
    obj = cl1()
    assert obj.a1 is None
    assert obj.a2 is None
    assert obj.a3 == 0
    assert obj.a4 == 10000

I expect the code of test that will work

Since a1 and a2 have type str, the default value (first argument of Field) should be string, not None. And if you want to make them optional, specify type asstr | None
